# bash function handling of parameter with commands, pipe and variables

Tags: bash, function, parameter-passing

I try to pass a parameter which contain a commands, pipe and variables to a function.

```
#!/bin/bash

CMD()
{
    echo "#TST# `date` CMD: $1"
}

CMD "ntpq -pn | awk '{ printf "%s %s\n", $9,$10 }'"
```

As result I get

```
#TST# Tue Aug  4 16:15:50 CEST 2015 CMD: ntpq -pn | awk '{ printf %s
```

I searched and tried several things for hours but i get not the expected result of the complete command.

How can I handle such a parameter with a commands, pipe and variables?

Comment: Do you want to pass the command to `CMD`, or the *result* of the command? If the latter, just use `CMD "$(ntpq -pn | awk '...')"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first. You **cannot** reliably stick complex commands in strings. See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for discussion of this.

That being said your issue is "simpler" than that.

Your issue is one of quoting not doing what you expect.

You expect this command:

```
CMD "ntpq -pn | awk '{ printf "%s %s\n", $9,$10 }'"
```

to be parsed by the shell as:

```
[CMD] ["ntpq -pn | awk '{ printf "%s %s\n", $9,$10 }'"]
```

but it isn't. The "internal" quotes mess it up (because they aren't internal to the shell).

The shell actually parses this:

```
[CMD] ["ntpq -pn | awk '{ printf "%s] [%s\n", $9,$10 }'"]
```

and so `CMD` gets **two** arguments and not one and thus you have your problem when you try to print out `$1` in the `CMD` function.

Escape those "inner" double quotes and you (almost) get what you want:

```
$ CMD "ntpq -pn | awk '{ printf \"%s %s\n\", $9,$10 }'"
#TST# Tue Aug  4 10:28:24 EDT 2015 CMD: ntpq -pn | awk '{ printf "%s %s\n", ,0 }
```

For the record a syntax highlighting editor would have clued you in to this as would have pasting your code into http://www.shellcheck.net/.

That still isn't quite right though as `$9` and `$10` went missing. That's because the shell evaluated them in the double quote context. You need to escape the `$` there too to prevent that:

```
CMD "ntpq -pn | awk '{ printf \"%s %s\n\", \$9,\$10 }'"
```

That all being said I want to reiterate that [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) makes this a bad general idea (assuming you expect to use that command at some point).

Comment: Many thanks for your information. I will read the BASH FAQ 500.

Answer (score 4):

In the call of `CMD`, simply escape the double quotes and the `$` symbols.

Change

```
CMD "ntpq -pn | awk '{ printf "%s %s\n", $9,$10 }'"
```

to

```
CMD "ntpq -pn | awk '{ printf \"%s %s\n\", \$9,\$10 }'"
```

**Note** : Not doing so will also expand variables. See [this link](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) on bash quotation

Comment: Many thanks for your information. I will read this part of the bash wiki.

Comment: Nice catch about `$9` and `$10`.